# Dependency inject a custom file provider for runtime compilation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-5.0, runtime-compilation, fileprovider

I am experimenting with [loading views from a database](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/301/loading-asp-net-core-mvc-views-from-a-database-or-other-location), and as suggested in the article one might want to add some caching to prevent hitting the database every time.

`ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddMemoryCache();

services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(opt =>
    {
        opt.FileProviders.Add(new DatabaseFileProvider(Configuration["AppSettings:SQLConnectionString"]));
    });
```

`DatabaseFileProvider` constructor:

```
private string _connection;

public DatabaseFileProvider(string connection)
{
    _connection = connection;
}
```

How do I dependency inject an instance of `IMemoryCache` to the `DatabaseFileProvider` class?, as one can do with e.g. a singleton:

`ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSingleton<AppUtils>();
```

`AppUtils` constructor:

```
private static IMemoryCache _cache;

public AppUtils(IMemoryCache cache)
{
    _cache = cache;
}
```

Comment: Configure the options via DI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options#use-di-services-to-configure-options

Comment: @Nkosi -- If you could provide an answer with a sample how that should look like, where I get both Options and IMemoryCache injected into the DatabaseFileProvider, I would be very grateful, as I can't see how that should be done (I am a really newbie when it comes to ASP.NET Core and its ways to be set up/configured).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use DI services to configure `MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions` directly

Assuming a target provider like

```
public class DatabaseFileProvider : IFileProvider {
    private string connection;
    private IMemoryCache cache;

    public DatabaseFileProvider(string connection, IMemoryCache cache) {
        this.connection = connection;
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    //...

}
```

Creating the provider with the aid of the DI services will allow for any registered dependencies to be resolved and explicitly injected using the deferred configuration delegate.

Reference [Use DI services to configure options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options#use-di-services-to-configure-options)

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddMemoryCache();

services
    .AddOptions<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>() 
    .Configure<IServiceProvider>((options, sp) => { //<-- Configuration here
        var cs = Configuration["AppSettings:SQLConnectionString"]);
        var provider = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<DatabaseFileProvider>(sp, cs);
        options.FileProviders.Add(provider);
    });

services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(); //remove configuration delegate here
```

`Configure` allows the use of up to five services to configure options, but if a `IServiceProvider` is injected, the provider can be used in resolve more dependencies if needed.

If that service locator approach is not preferred, the setup can be rearranged to follow a more pure DI design.

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddMemoryCache();

service.AddTransient<IFileProvider, DatabaseFileProvider>(sp => {
    var cs = Configuration["AppSettings:SQLConnectionString"]);
    var provider = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<DatabaseFileProvider>(sp, cs);
    return provider;
});

//... register other providers if any

services
    .AddOptions<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>() 
    .Configure<IEnumerable<IFileProvider>>((options, providers) => {
        //add all registered providers
        foreach(IFileProvider provider in providers) {
            options.FileProviders.Add(provider);
        }
    });

services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Comment: I have a concrete IFileProvider that has dependencies on scoped services.  If I use this solution, I get the error "Cannot resolve scoped service {path to my class} from root provider."  How can we get around this?

Comment: @ctorx which approach did you use from the solution? The first or the second?

Comment: I actually tried both with no luck.  I'm essentially needing the IFileProvider implementation to be able to resolve a scoped instance of an Entity Framework DBContext so that I can use it to fetch razor views from a context.

Comment: @ctorx Then create a scope via the provider to resolve the context.

Comment: Thank you.  That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: None of my razor views compile when I do this, I get errors that basic stuff like System is not found